# current_user not working in User model. I'm using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, model

I'm learning Ruby on Rails and having hard time defining my current user in User model.

My user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :confirmable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

...

```
def downgrade
  self.role = :standard
  current_user.wikis.each { |wiki| wiki.make_public }
  save
end
```

When I call wikis on current_user I get no method error. I thought devise provides current_user method. Please help and thank you!

Comment: Please paste the full error message. We don't know which method is unknown. Is it `current_user` or `wikis` ?

Comment: Yes, `Devise` defines `current_user` as helper method so you can use it both in your controllers and templates. Check [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers)

Answer (score 1):

`current_user` is a controller method and is *not* available in your model. However, I believe that you wish to simply reference the User instance in scope. Try doing this, assuming that `wikis` is an association or method in the User class.

```
def downgrade
  self.role = :standard
  wikis.each { |wiki| wiki.make_public }
end
```

`downgrade` is an instance method of the User class, which means when it must be invoked on an instance of that class. You might have code like `current_user.downgrade` in your controller, where `current_user` is an instance of User.

Within instance methods the "current" instance is referenced by `self`, such as `self.wikis` (calls the `wikis` method on the current instance). However `self` can often be omitted. `wikis` does the same thing as `self.wikis`.

One exception to that is attribute assignment for which `self` is required.

```
self.role = :standard  # invokes the role= method. Same as role=(:stardard)
role = :standard  # This will not work as expected! It creates a local variable named "role".
```

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot.